# How to come back from android preview version?

Tags: android

If I install **android preview version** of any SDK in my device, so, can I come back to previous stable version? Suppose I install **android M preview** version on nexus 5 having **Lollipop** 5.1 can I again roll back to **Lollipop 5.1** or need to wait 6.0 main release?

If yes, please provide procedure to do that.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question..
Need to flash final release version of Android OS similar as preview version.